# File upload taking too much time in iPhone application

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am working on an app where I have to upload a picture and some text to a php script. I am using POST request to upload image and text. The upload is done successfully but it takes lot of time in uploading, usually 40-50 seconds where image size is 300-400kb. My internet is not too slow and I have tested the api from a web page, it works quite fast from there.

If I call that API without image and only text, it doesn't take much time and completes quickly but whenever I send it with image it takes too much time.

Following is my code:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.myurl.com"]];
        [client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

        NSDictionary *simpleParams = @{ @"password": password,@"token": [defaults objectForKey:@"token"],@"array_receiver": selectedContact,@"message": txtMessage.text,@"time_allowed": txtTime.text,@"id_sender": [defaults objectForKey:@"id_user"] };
        NSLog(@"simpleParams %@",simpleParams);

        NSMutableURLRequest* request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/send_message.php" parameters: simpleParams constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            if(myimage){
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(myimage)
                                            name:@"uploaded_image"
                                        fileName:@"filename.png"
                                        mimeType:@"image/png"];
            }
        }];
        NSLog(@"sending...........");

        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        NSLog(@"sent........... %@",request);
```

Comment: Is your server support streaming upload? It will be somewhat faster than currently you did.. Because you did wrongly, concept of multipart is somwhat different.

Comment: no I don't think so but why do we need streaming server to upload a image file of 300 or 400kb

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried to do? that means, need to know what you have understood?

Comment: I am trying to send a message with some text and a image in a single request. It is working fine but taking lot of time

Comment: I have seen what you have done. I heard about logic. k. You've tried to send image data in postbody. That's why it's taking too much time. concept of multipartdata is "separate big file into multi part and send concurrently with multipart in one request"

Comment: If you tried with streaming, it will buffer with your data and streaming from buffer. Always JSON format postbody design to carry small data..

Comment: but I don't have streaming server, how should I do it now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44477/discussion-between-mani-and-pankaj)